# Why is manganese oxide precipitated during the syn hydroxylation of alkenes with permanganate ion?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox

During the hydrolysis step, after the formation of the heterocyclic ring, hydrogen permanganate ion is formed but the final product is manganese oxide precipitate.

My point - why would permanganate be reduced in the first place. And if it would, then why the change to +4 oxidation state specifically, why not to some other oxidation state.

Answer (score 0):

Manganese Oxide is a decay product of permanganate, if the solution is not very acidic it will be formed for sure after a redox reaction.

It might do the diol forming syn addition but some fraction seemed to reduce itself.

Comment: Manganese oxide is the product regardless of the nature of the solution.

Comment: Very low pH dissolve MnO2, you can't get it always due to that. But when you get, it is an insoluble and highly durable oxide and it will precipitate, my labcoat has them for more than 4 yours and they never got themselves clean no matter how hard we did. So you are sure reaction formed MnO2, and it is apparent that it is insoluble, so what is the question ?